# Play framework for Java? version 1.x.x or 2.x.x

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I just want to know if the application is going to be developed in Java, is it better to go for Play 1.x.x or 2.x.x?

and How long the version 1.x.x will be supported? Is it an active fork?

Thanks

Comment: Go with version 2.1.1 which is the latest (and greatest?). If you don't have any special reasons to stick with 1.x.x then don't.

Comment: even if no developer in the team knows Scala?

Comment: There is still fully Java support. Only the core parts have been developed in Scala. The API's are still available in Java **and** Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you should read [What are the major differences between Play Framework 1.0 and 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189893/what-are-the-major-differences-between-play-framework-1-0-and-2-0/8193355#8193355). 
2.x is in active development, how ever if you have trouble you must read the core-code which is scala and you must handle with SBT, which is more Scala Build Tool than Simple Build Tool.

For play 1.x there is a fork yalp, but it's in the beginning and will break with the old api, but it's plain java.

If you need some of the features of play2.x (responsive web in meaning of a server which has a good responsiveness nothing to do with webdesign.) I think play with scala is the best choice. If you have a simple application, play1.x does everything you need.

So check the tutorials to get a feeling.

Comment: `Feature of Play2 (repsonisve web)`: Waaa, do you even know what responsive web is?

Comment: at least one of the arguments the core team use. How ever I don't no what you want to achieve with the comment. If you want that someone explain it to you, create a question, if you think play2 doesn't fits your criteria wrote down where it is violated.

Comment: Here is the wikipedia definition of Responsive :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design As you may state, it has nothing to do with Play. What you probably wanted to say was `realtime`.

Comment: @i.am.michiel Well you talk about design I'm about the server responsiveness.

Comment: Responsive web app. i.e. asynchronous, able to cope with heavy loads without huge overhead on the server, handle huge file uploads...

Comment: Come on, type : `Responsive web app` on Google and tell me at least result on the first page talks about server load and not design and I'll agree with you.

Answer (score 4):

Start with Play 2+ reason is simple, Play 1.x is NO longer officially developed by Zenexity. It's only in maintenance mode now.

A fork has appeared a couple of months ago : [Yalp Framework](https://github.com/yalpframework/yalp).

Answer (score 3):

Basically 1.x.x is still around because it is really different from 2.x.x

converting Play1 projects to Play2 is almost recoding everything so Play has to keep on supporting Play1 to keep the "customers" that are already doing production with 1.x.x

If you are starting a project now, be it Java or Scala, I advise to get Play 2.1.x since it has the latest and most awesome features. And it also works with the latest versions of scala (which I am aware is not relevent to your question).

TLDR : 1.x.x is outdated but still supported because a lot of people are still using in production since it is not easy to port a 1.x project to 2.x